# How can I get consistent paths when using depends_on on archive_file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have this terraform file

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "null_resource" "snapshot_pip_receiver" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cd ${path.module}/lambdas; make lint-snapshot collect-snapshot"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda-zip" {
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.snapshot_pip_receiver
  ]

  source_dir  = "${path.module}/lambda/"
  output_path = "${path.module}/es-snapshot.zip"
  type        = "zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "es_snapshot_lambda" {
  depends_on       = [data.archive_file.lambda-zip]
  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path
  function_name    = "test-lambda"
  role             = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path)
  handler          = "es-snapshot.lambda_handler"
  runtime          = "python2.7"
  timeout          = 10

}
```

`terraform plan` is giving this in output

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

Error: Error in function call

  on main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "es_snapshot_lambda":
  26:   source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path)
    |----------------
    | data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path is "./es-snapshot.zip"

Call to function "filebase64sha256" failed: no file exists at es-snapshot.zip.
```

What I have done so far :-

1. If I remove `depends_on` from `archive_file` then it run successfully but I need depends_on as null_resource needs to execute first to build the app.
2. I tried to put explicit `depends_on` in `aws_lambda_function` but no use.
3. I replaced `aws_lambda_function` with another `null_resource` calling `output_path` and it ran successfully.

How can I get consistent paths when using depends_on on archive_file?

Comment: I would replace `filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path)` with `filebase64sha256("${path.module}/es-snapshot.zip")`

Comment: still complaining that file does not exist.

Comment: I see that `cd ${path.module}/lambdas;` vs `source_dir  = "${path.module}/lambda/"` is that `S` maybe a typo?

Comment: need to replace `filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path)` with `filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_base64sha256)`. Not sure what it does but that is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various Terraform functions that read files from disk are exclusively for reading files that exist statically on disk as part of the configuration. They are not suitable for reading files *created by* the configuration, because configuration evaluation happens before execution.

Fortunately, you don't actually need a function here at all because `archive_file` automatically exports the SHA256 hash of the created archive encoded with base64:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "es_snapshot_lambda" {
  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path
  function_name    = "test-lambda"
  role             = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_base64sha256
  handler          = "es-snapshot.lambda_handler"
  runtime          = "python2.7"
  timeout          = 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is some internal "cleverness" in **archive_file** mangling the **output_path** between when it is set as an argument and when you read it back. It's technically an argument, not an [attribute of the archive_file resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/archive/d/archive_file.html#attributes-reference), so there may be no guarantees about its value if you read it.

Given that the paths are used multiple times, computing them once in a locals block should avoid this problem of inconsistent values:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

locals {
  lambda_dir = "${path.module}/lambdas/"
  lambda_zip_path = "${path.module}/es-snapshot.zip"
}

resource "null_resource" "snapshot_pip_receiver" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cd \"${local.lambda_dir}\" ; make lint-snapshot collect-snapshot"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda-zip" {
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.snapshot_pip_receiver
  ]

  source_dir  =  local.lambda_dir
  output_path = local.lambda_zip_path
  type        = "zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "es_snapshot_lambda" {
  depends_on       = [data.archive_file.lambda-zip]
  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path
  function_name    = "test-lambda"
  role             = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(local.lambda_zip_path)
  handler          = "es-snapshot.lambda_handler"
  runtime          = "python2.7"
  timeout          = 10
}
```